# Shopify Multiple Variants and Option - Error "name cant be blank"

Tags: php, shopify, shopify-api

I'm trying to create a product with multiple variants and option. I used the example json on the shopify api documentation. But its giving me an error. Seems the example is wrong?

```
require_once("inc/functions.php");
$shop = "abc";
setGlobalVariables( $shop) ;


$product_json = '{
  "product": {
    "title": "Burton Custom Freestyle 151",
    "body_html": "<strong>Good snowboard!</strong>",
    "vendor": "Burton",
    "product_type": "Snowboard",
    "variants": [
      {
        "option1": "Blue",
        "option2": "155"
      },
      {
        "option1": "Black",
        "option2": "159"
      }
    ],
    "options": [
      {
        "name": "Color",
        "values": [
          "Blue",
          "Black"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Size",
        "values": [
          "155",
          "159"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}';

$products_array=json_decode($product_json, true);

$modified_product = shopify_call($token, $shop, "/admin/api/".$shopifyVer."/products.json",$products_array,'POST');
$modified_product_response = $modified_product['response'];



echo "<pre>";
print_r($modified_product_response);
echo "</pre>";

echo "Successfully Inserted.";
```

This is the code i used. Hope someone can help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: Show us how's your `shopify_call()` function look like

Answer (score 0):

Remove this code:

```php
$products_array=json_decode($product_json, true);
```

and replace your Shopify call function code with this code:

```php
$modified_product = shopify_call($token, $shop, "/admin/api/".$shopifyVer."/products.json",$product_json,'POST', array("Content-Type: application/json"));
```